# Why Do All New WordPress Themes Have Empty Style.css File?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I am completely lost. I have always made all my changes to a theme via style.css as one would expect. However, when I went to look at and edit the default/stock style.css file for the WordPress theme “Go” and “Twenty-Twenty-Three” there is no code inside of it. I even double checked the themes’ GitHub page and verified this is how it is, I don’t have a corrupt file or anything like that. **What am I missing here?**

As you can see in the source code, there IS a folder labeled css in there somewhere, but there are multiple .css files, and none of them are named "style.css" so I don't know which one to edit. I tried making edits to style-shared.css, but that didn't seem to do anything or make any changes stick.

Below is the GitHub for the source code for the theme "Go" that I mentioned above. Thank you very much

https://github.com/godaddy-wordpress/go

Comment: Did you edit style.css via admin or ftp?

Comment: Thx for the reply! I meant even before I made any edits to style.css, it's a tiny file and doesn't have any css code in it all, like there always is. It looks like Wordpress changed the way their themes are setup. Updated/edited original post to be more specific and reflect the aforementioned.

Comment: WP uses the root `style.css` to define the **theme** - you don't need to put any CSS in it. If you notice in the GoDaddy Go theme, the root `style.css` has all the information about the theme (if you go to Appearance -> Themes, you'll see how it's displayed, e.g. version, theme name, etc.). It's better to make a child theme rather than edit the main theme - since if there are updates to the Go theme, your changes will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

in block themes, style handling is usually done via theme.json, but you can still use **style.css** to add your customizations.

### Adding your customizations

The best way doing this is *creating a child theme* and making changes to it. In that way, when an update to the parent theme is released, your customizations will not be lost.

The child theme inherits the features of the parent theme and you can customize only what you need.

### Create a wordpress child theme. It's easy !!!

As an example, let's say we want to do this for **Twenty Twenty four** theme.
Basically, we need to create a folder for the child theme with these three files:

1. **style.css** (style customization)
2. **functions.php** (It will be responsible, among other things, for loading your css)
3. **screenshot.png** (image of your child theme that will appear in the list of themes installed on your WP)

*Creating a folder to hold the files above (The child theme folder)*

The folder must be created inside "***wp-content/themes***". The folder name must be the same as the name of the parent theme followed by "***-child***".

Considering our example theme ***Twenty Twenty four***, the folder name for the child theme would be: ***twentytwentyfour-child*** (lowercase, no space, with -child at the end)

See the figure for the child theme folder right after the parent theme folder:

[image: child-theme-folder-wordpress]

---

***Now that we have the folder created, let's create the files !!!***

---

**1 Creating a style.css for your child theme**

Copy style.css from

```
wp-content/themes/twentytwentyfour/
```

to

```
wp-content/themes/twentytwentyfour-child/
```

Inside the style.css change the **Theme name** to your child theme name

Theme Name: Twenty Twenty-Four Child

[image: style.css for wordpress child theme]

**2 Creating a functions.php file**

Add the ***functions.php*** file to the child theme folder as shown below

```php
<?php
/**
 * TwentyTwentyFour-Child Theme functions and definitions
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
 *
 * @package TwentyTwentyFour-Child
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

/**
 * Enqueue styles
 */
function child_enqueue_styles()
{

    $parenthandle = 'parent-style';
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    wp_enqueue_style(
        $parenthandle,
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array(),  // if the parent theme code has a dependency, copy it to here
        $theme->parent()->get('Version')
    );

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array($parenthandle),
        $theme->get('Version') // this only works if you have Version in the style header
    );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles', 15);
?>
```

**3 Creating a screenshot file**

You can just copy the ***screenshot.png*** from your parent theme folder.

**And voilà ...**

you have created a child theme where you can make your style customizations safely.

Make your changes inside style.css which is located in the child theme folder. It will be loaded by the functions.php of your child theme.

For more details, you can check the official documentation at:

[Create a Child Theme](https://wordpress.com/support/themes/child-themes/)

[Child Themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses and help guys, looks like I found the answer. These themes are a newer type of Wordpress theme. These themes are known as "block  themes" which make use of the Wordpress's site editor instead.

More on this directly from a Wordpress Moderator himself:

"This means they make use of a concept called “Global Styles” allowing the theme to put all its styles into code in a theme.json file instead, which again allows the users to make any style changes from the admin interface instead."